# Disable tests compilation in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a java maven project, and I make some changes to it. Those changes broke compilation of the tests, and for now, I don't want to fix them (as I don't know if my idea works or not).

Is there a way to altogether disable tests compilation and make my project run?

Comment: You may remove "Build" action from your Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: Yes, but I need to build my production code (without tests). If I remove build action I won't be able to build.

Comment: So, you may mark "test" folder as excluded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is.

Got to `Settings -> Build,Ex.. -> Compiler -> Excludes` and press the `+` button:
[image]

select the path you want to exclude. In your case it's the test folder:
[image]

Check the `recursive` checkbox on the right side and you should see that your test folder has no a little `x` on the folder to mark it as excluded:

BTW: Remeber these little `x`, because Intellij IDEA provides an intention to exclude certain package from compilation.
Executing that intention by accident could lead to a long journey of searching and asking in order to understand why certain packages aren't build anymore.

[image]